# Adding an imageview over another imageview programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have an Activity with a layout as given below. I want to add another imageview with respect to the imageviews inside the layout (bottom right part).

How can I add the yellow and red imageview with respect to the imageviews in linear layout ?

Or Is it easy to embed the two Images inside a relative layout/frame layout and show and hide them ?

Thanks and regards,

[image: My Layout for the activity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you are Looking for this. hope this will help you.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rr_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:scaleType="center" />



        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/img_edit_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_profile_image"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/img_profile_image"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img_profile_image"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:src="@mipmap/edit_thumb" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I added the Circle Imageview in relative layout with
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
along with some margin. Works out OK. But the problem is configuring the Margin Values and Size Values for Multiple Dimensions

Answer (score 2):

Using **FrameLayout** you are able to solve this problem

**Try This:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/gray_ea"
   android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using frame Layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>


    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>


    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have used hardcoded height width you can remove or update them as per your images size

Answer (score 0):

Set orientation for outer LinearLayout vertical, and use two RelativeLayout. Put imageViews in the RelativeLayouts. Just add them, `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"`  and `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`. That's all.